# Allow centered element to overflow to left of screen as well as right

Tags: html, css

I am working with a fixed width and centered footer that contains an inline list.

I'd like to be able to reduce the window size and have my element overflow to the left as well as the right, keeping the center of the content centered.

How can I acheive this when the elements in my footer are inline?

Picture example: [image]

Edit: example

```
#p-wrapper {
    width:100%; 
    position:fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 25%;
    height: 25vh;
    min-height: 11em;
    max-height: 14em;
    padding: 0;
}

#p-body {
    background: grey;
    border-top: 5px solid black;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

/* Tuts */
ul {
    padding: 0;
    height: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: visible;
    overflow-x: visible;
    text-align: center;
}
    li {
        list-style:none;
        display:inline-block;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        background:#fff;
        height: 10em;
        width: 5em;
        position:relative;
        border: 1px solid black;
        border-top-left-radius: 4px;
        border-top-right-radius: 4px;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 8px;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;       
    }

<div id="p-wrapper">
        <div id="p-body">
            <ul id="piano">
                 <!-- Start Octave -->
                <li class="white">
                <li class="black">
                <li class="white">
                <li class="black">
                <li class="white">
                <li class="white">
                <li class="black">
                <li class="white">
                <li class="black">
                <li class="white">
                <li class="black">
                <li class="white">
                <!-- End Octave -->
                <!-- Start Octave -->
                <li class="white">
                <li class="black">
                <li class="white">
                <li class="black">
                <li class="white">
                <li class="white">
                <li class="black">
                <li class="white">
                <li class="black">
                <li class="white">
                <li class="black">
                <li class="white">
                <!-- End Octave -->
                <!-- Start Octave -->
                <li class="white">
                <li class="black">
                <li class="white">
                <li class="black">
                <li class="white">
                <li class="white">
                <li class="black">
                <li class="white">
                <li class="black">
                <li class="white">
                <li class="black">
                <li class="white">
                <!-- End Octave -->
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: could you show an example of what do you have for now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using `position: fixed` (or `absolute`) and then adjust the `left` offset to 50% and the use the CSS transform property to translate the block element 50% to the left.

This may work but the details of implemention will depend on the rest of you layout.

```css
.footer {
  width: 500px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px dotted blue;
  position: fixed;
  left: 50%; 
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="footer">This footer text is centered and has a fixed width.</div>
```

Comment: Your snippet works, but in my case i have inline element within a fixed div.

Comment: Actually scratch that; your answer worked, i just needed to set the position to absolute